# Using number_format to get decimals

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

I got a few values I want to sum up and check agains another number like this:

```
$a = '15';
$b = '5,50';
$c = '-10';
$to_pay = '10,50';
$formated_total = number_format(($a+$b+($c)), 2, ',', ' ');
$this->assertEquals($to_pay, $formated_total);
```

the asser part is a selenium function I am using so dont think about that, it's just supposed to check if the 2 values are the same. Now the result I get is:

```
 - Expected
 + Actual
 -'10,50'
 +'10,00'
```

Why am I losing the value from the decimals?

Comment: Where are your values coming from?

Comment: If you need to parse localized float string, check the comments on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use "," as decimal point it's not excel. In PHP you need to use DOT

Change your numbers to:

```
$a = '15';
$b = '5.50';
$c = '-10';
$to_pay = '10.50';
```

or even better solution would be treat them as numbers not as strings

Change your numbers to:

```
$a = 15;
$b = 5.50;
$c = -10;
$to_pay = 10.50;
```

In that way you would get error if you tried using `,` instead of `.`

You can also simplify this line:

```
$formated_total = number_format(($a+$b+($c)), 2, ',', ' ');
```

to

```
$formated_total = number_format($a+$b+$c, 2, ',', ' ');
```

You may be curious why the result is 10. It's because during casting it to number php parser checks in `5,50` the number at the begining which is 5 and ignores the rest.

From [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

Comment: Thnaks, I retrieved the values from different parts of the page and on the page they where displayed with a "," instead of a ".", but a simple str_replace fixed it. thanks

Comment: you're welcome :) you can always use is_float() function to check if it's proper float number.

Answer (score 2):

Because comma is not a valid decimal point. You need to "convert" `$b` and `$to_pay` values to use dots.